# Attempting to tap a serial connection between hardware and software, but application takes control over the serial port

Tags: windows-10, serial-port

We're trying to monitor the serial messages sent/recieved between a hardware device and a piece of software, however when trying to monitor the device, the software is taking control of the port and it cannot be monitored.

The Serial device is (as far as I know) UART over USB - That's the driver that we needed to install to get it to work.

Are there any ways to "split" or "tap" the connection, without having to buy an expensive hardware tap?

We've already attempted to use a "splitter" application, along with com0com to achieve this, but with no success.

Comment: https://www.serial-splitter.com/use-cases/best-rs232-splitters/

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what we tried. Tried the Share/Alias and Split options and got "permisison denied, port in use"

Comment: There's a plethora of software utilities to monitor serial ports. If none of them work, maybe your serial to usb adapter is the reason. You could try finding some hardware that provides you with a true serial port and run the monitoring on that.

Comment: Thanks! - I'll definitely take a look into this and see how we get on